# Having trouble with download_app and coursebuilder

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I inherited an appengine coursebuilder project a couple months ago, and we've been trying to upgrade to a more recent version of coursebuilder. In order to do this, the first step is to download local version of the course. 
Whenever I run appcfg.py download_app -A $projectID -V $versionNumber ./folderToSaveTo

It downloads a different version of the course, one that looks like an old test version with old placeholder text, all links to lessons set to private, etc.

When I look at the versions of the course in the appengine dashboard, there is only a single version, so I'm not sure what it's even downloading.

Alternatively, it was suggested I use the ETL tool provided with coursebuilder to download the files instead, but that had a bunch of other issues associated with it as well. Previously I had asked the question directly on the [coursebuilder forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/course-builder-forum/general-troubleshooting/5vzidyaepsk) where the ETL tool was initially suggested.

Thanks in advance for any help,
-Tyler Nolan

Answer (score 1):

appcfg's `download_app` will only look within the default module. You should check if there are any drop-downs in the Developers Console UI which will allow you to look into whether there are other modules.

[`gcloud preview app modules download`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/modules/download) on the other hand, does allow you to specify modules.

Hopefully this helps you find the "real version" of your app.

It's also possible that what you download is displaying default data because it's not being viewed in a manner which is properly connected to the database, so it falls back to look like that.